# Android Sending PCM byte[] Over network

Tags: android, audio, network-programming

We have raw pcm bytes[] / short[] we want to send it over network but what makes problem is when we send it over network it does plays very fast at receiver side.How to make it play like normal sound.I know its something due to I send byte[] at once it should be sent in chunk according to sampling rate but need help in how we can send byte[] with such sampling rate.

Normally when we send data with Mic it works correct but we want to send pcm byte[] we have.

Comment: you mean while you are sending data, the receiver is playing at the same? why not wait until all data arrive ?

Comment: We cant control receiver side its IP cam who receives audio byte[] at another side.what we have in control is at sending side only. when we send bytes using mic it does works well may be due to it control the sending process automatically.